# How to solve the inverse problem of least-squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

Focusing on following least squares problem:

$$\min\limits_{V} \lVert Z - WV \rVert _{_F}^2$$

$$Z∈{R}^{m\times n},\quad W∈{R}^{m\times k},\quad V∈{R}^{k\times n},\quad k\lt m\lt n $$

This problem can be easily solved given $Z$ and $W$. I assume the solution of this problem as $\overline{V}$.

My question is that,  how can we recover $W$ by $\overline{V}$ and $Z$?

I found something called *inverse optimization*, but cannot figure out the relationship between them.

Comment: [cross-posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302024/how-to-solve-the-inverse-problem-of-least-squares)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the initial least squares problem can be written in terms of the pseudoinverse
$${\bar V} = W^+Z$$
Then several days later, you still have $({\bar V},Z)$ but have somehow lost the definition of $W$. 

You can try the following 
$$\eqalign{
W^+ &= {\bar V}Z^+ \cr
W &= ({\bar V}Z^+)^+ \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your answer you assume 
$${W^+} = W^+ZZ^+$$ I am not sure if it is true.

Comment: It'll be true so long as $\,{\rm rank}(Z) = m\,\,$

Comment: Thank you. @greg  Your answer is very valuable. What if rank($Z$) <$m$?

Comment: @greg are you sure? $(e_1)^+ = e_1^T$, but $w^T = w^Te_1e_1^T$ does not hold for all vectors $w$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The question stipulates that $Z\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n}$ and $m<n$. Your counter-example is $e_1\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times 1}$, which does not satisfy the second criteria since $m>1\,\,$

Comment: @greg Correct, but it's not hard to construct an analogous counterexample with $Z=[e_1,e_2]$. The point is that $W^+ \neq W^+ZZ^+$, in general, even if $Z$ has full rank, as Lee pointed out, too.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni If $Z$ has full rank, then $Z^+=Z^T(ZZ^T)^{-1}$ and $ZZ^+=I$. But if $Z$ is rank deficient, there's no way to recover $W\,\,$

Comment: Oh sorry OK I get it now, you are correct. So it seems that we can recover $W$ from $V$ but not $V$ from $W$? Very unexpected...